# List all unique combinations

Tags: unique, combinations, extract, stata

I have a large dataset containing city names and matching postcodes. City names and postcodes might appear several times. I need to get an overview which cities and postcodes I have in the dataset. Therefore, I want to extract a list showing me only the unique combinations of cities and postcodes.

```
Example: 

City    Postcode

x   123
y   456
x   123
z   342
p   256
z   342
x   321
```

I want to get:

```
City    Postcode

x   123
y   456
z   342
p   256
x   321
```

I managed to do that in R, but I do not know how to do that in Stata.....

Comment: This question was overlooked (by me and perhaps others) because it lacked a Stata tag (now added).

Answer (score 1):

As often happens, the request for display of **unique** combinations is better phrased in terms of **distinct** combinations. The interest is not in those combinations that occur just once. For an overview of distinct observations in Stata, see [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042).

Here are two ways to approach the problem. First, the `egen` function `tag()` tags just one of each group of observations identical on the variables specified.

```
clear 
input str1 City    Postcode
x   123
y   456
x   123
z   342
p   256
z   342
x   321
end 

egen tag = tag(City Postcode) 
list City Postcode if tag , noobs 

  +-----------------+
  | City   Postcode |
  |-----------------|
  |    x        123 |
  |    y        456 |
  |    z        342 |
  |    p        256 |
  |    x        321 |
  +-----------------+
```

Second, `groups` is a convenience command that by default gives frequencies and percents for distinct cross-combinations. You must install this before you can use it. You can show more (and indeed fewer) results using options.

```
. ssc install groups 
. groups City Postcode 

  +-----------------------------------+
  | City   Postcode   Freq.   Percent |
  |-----------------------------------|
  |    p        256       1     14.29 |
  |    x        123       2     28.57 |
  |    x        321       1     14.29 |
  |    y        456       1     14.29 |
  |    z        342       2     28.57 |
  +-----------------------------------+
```

For some general comments on `groups`, see [this post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1403309-groups-updated-on-ssc).

Answer (score 0):

look up the duplicates command.